# dll not being copied to output directory, even with Copy Local flag (<Private>true</Private>)

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, msbuild-4.0

We have a project called WWW which references another project in the same solution called Framework.

Framework uses a Nuget which has a dependency on another Nuget package called iSynaptic.

The Framework.csproj xml says:

```
<Private>true</Private>
```

and the Visual Studio UI says

```
Copy Local = True.
```

However, when I rebuild the solution, WWW/bin does not contain the dll for iSynaptic.Core.

Here is the full xml for the reference:

```
<Reference Include="iSynaptic.Core">
  <HintPath>..\packages\iSynaptic.Core.0.1.3\lib\iSynaptic.Core.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>true</Private>
</Reference>
```

I've also tried permutations in case of case sensitivity: true, True & TRUE

Additionally, I have tried adding a dummy class file in Framework that explicitly uses a class from the iSynapticCore.dll

```
using iSynaptic;
using iSynaptic.Core;

namespace Framework.Bootstrap
{    
    public static class Dummy
    {
        public static int GetCode()
        {
            return iSynaptic.HashCode.MixJenkins32(0);
        }
    }
}
```

I've found examples of making a class that inherits a class from the dll. But unfortunately, none of the classes in iSynaptic.Core are public.

I have also tried deleting and re-adding the references through visual studio as well as by manually re-adding the xml by hand.

I have also tried using visual studio to set Copy Local to false, then save, then set Copy Local back to true, then save.

I checked the GAC and the assembly is NOT loaded in the GAC

I have tried building through both Visual Studio 2012 and MSBuild from the command line:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe /target:Clean,Rebuild
```

**Any ideas what could be causing the dll to not get copied to the WWW/bin output directory on build?**

Comment: Is Framework.dll copied to the bin directory? In Visual Studio under the Build -> Configuration menu, do all projects have the Build checkbox checked?